# Keeping a webView contained in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-webview

Hey everyone! Im pretty new to Android and I have a webView under 2 other widgets on the screen(Or w/e you call it). But when ever I navigate the webView, its changes to full screen and i cant see my other widgets. Ive looked all over Google but couldn't find anything, is there some way I can fix this?

Im using this code to navigate:

```
webView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com/");
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
   }
});
```

when you do `webView.loadUrl("www.example.com")` or if there is a redirection when a hyperlink is clicked or something similar, the android device browser is started. I believe you are stuck with this. Try pasting the above code before you call the `webView.loadUrl("www.example.com")`

What we are essentially doing is asking the webview to load the url, instead of opening it in the device browser.